# LACP and Loadbalancing?

Tags: lacp

I'm currently in a discussion about how LACP and load balancing is working.

Assume, there are two servers, both using 4 nics (1Gbit) and they are connected to the same switch with aggregated Links.

Which "statements" are true?

- Each server could *theoretically* deliver 4 Gbit of data, if there are enough clients requesting data (at least one per link)
- The servers can talk to each other with 4Gbit/s.
- The servers can talk to each other with 1Gbit/s, because the algortihms to balance traffic will always choose the same NIC out of the 4 available links.
- When using *Round-Robin*, the servers can communicate at a speed > 1GBit/s, but will encounter out-of-order-packets, which needs to be resorted and at the end resulting in a much lower transfer speed than 4GB/s.
- A connection between hostA and hostB will never be faster than the speed of a single link, even if you are grouping 8 or more nics.

cheers,
dognose

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @ewwhite No, i'm just trying not to push the answer in the direction i'd like to hear by saying: "It is like THIS, am I right?" :)

Answer (score 2):

Two basic things to keep in mind:

- Traffic is distributed packet by packet
- All packets associated with a given “conversation” are
  transmitted on the same link to prevent mis-ordering

That second point has some variability between Operating Systems and implementations as to what is a "conversation" so the answers to some of your questions are not always the same. Generally if there are a lot of "conversations" the link will perform well but single stream benchmarking between two systems will be limited to what a single link can provide.

Ref: PDF [IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregation (LAG)  what it is, and what it is not](http://www.ieee802.org/3/hssg/public/apr07/frazier_01_0407.pdf)

Comment: Thx for the answer and link. So it comes down to what a conversation is seen as. I especially like the conclusion: "LAG is good, but it’s not as good as a fatter pipe".